# Dropdown in table field causes vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind CSS, I have this table in my project.

```
<div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
 <table class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500">
  <thead class="text-xs text-white uppercase bg-gray-900">
   <tr>
    <th class="px-6 py-3">Name</th>
    <th class="px-6 py-3">Actions</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="bg-gray-50 border-b">
    <td class="px-6 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">John Doe</td>
    <td class="px-6 py-3">
     <div onclick="openTableDropdown(1)" class="relative cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center p-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-500">
      clickable icone
      <div id="tableDropdown-1" class="hidden bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-200 absolute bottom-0 left-1/2 transform translate-y-full -translate-x-1/2 z-10">
       <ul>
        <li class="px-6 pt-2 pb-1 hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-t-lg">Action 1</li>
        <li class="px-6 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200">Action 2</li>
        <li class="px-6 pt-1 pb-2 hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-b-lg">Action 3</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

And I have this simple function to toggle dropdown:

```
function openTableDropdown(id){
 var dropdown = document.getElementById(`tableDropdown-${id}`);
 dropdown.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

Everything works fine except when I open the dropdown in the last row of the table.

To display the element, the div show vertical scroll in the table. Is there any way to show the absolute element above the table?

This is how the output is right now, but I want to overlapping the element on the table and avoid vertical scroll.

[image: Actual output]

I tried to change z-index but it doesn't work.

**Edit:**
The problem is the class "overflow-x-auto" on the main div but I need that class to allow X scroll on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in your code.
Look at the following code:

```
<div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
    <table class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500">
        <thead class="text-xs text-white uppercase bg-gray-900">
            <tr>
                <th class="px-6 py-3">Name</th>
                <th class="px-6 py-3">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-gray-50 border-b">
                <td class="px-6 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">John Doe</td>
                <td class="px-6 py-3">
                    <div onclick="openTableDropdown(1)" class="relative cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center p-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-900 hover:text-gray-500">
                        clickable icone
                        <div id="tableDropdown-1" class="hidden bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-200 absolute top-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 z-10">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="px-6 pt-2 pb-1 hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-t-lg">Action 1</li>
                                <li class="px-6 py-1 hover:bg-gray-200">Action 2</li>
                                <li class="px-6 pt-1 pb-2 hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-b-lg">Action 3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Try this and let me know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. 
Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add your code jsfiddle or any other editor and share the link?

Comment: I found this question and the problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue).

I'm going to solve the situation in a different way. Thank you.